# How common is it to dedicate rocket launches to popular causes?

Tags: launch, history, public-involvement

The BBC's [Space Plane: Mysterious US military aircraft launches](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-52698133) says:

> The launch was dedicated to front line workers and those affected by the pandemic. A message including the words "America Strong" **[was written on the rocket's payload fairing](https://twitter.com/ulalaunch/status/1261295513594454016)**.

The video in that linked ULA tweet shows the following being stenciled on to the fairing:

> In memory of COVID-19 victims and tribute to all first responders and front-line workers
>
> AMERICA STRONG

(also a [video](https://youtu.be/XC8uqVe4px0))

**Question:** How common is it to dedicate rocket launches to popular and/or timely causes? Are there other notable examples of this?

Answers do not need to be limited to any specific country. (I remember once seeing a Japanese(?) launch with [manga characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga) painted on it for example, for that I've just asked [Was there a rocket launched to space with Japanese manga characters painted on it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44173/12102) separately.)

Comment: Pizza is popular! (and yes, it's real) https://media.ktvb.com/assets/GANNETT/images/005fdc4b-774f-4235-a5f5-a95f71c7112f/005fdc4b-774f-4235-a5f5-a95f71c7112f_1140x641.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble not exactly a dedication, but certainly a popular cause :-)