# Was there a rocket launched to space with Japanese manga characters painted on it?

Tags: launch, history, japan

In [How common is it to dedicate rocket launches to popular causes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44172/12102) I mentioned a launch for which I could not remember the details. I'd seen photos of a rocket, Japanese I believe, that would be launched to space, and on it were painted [manga characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga).

Is it possible to track this down and explain it's [five W's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Space Brothers (manga)] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uch%C5%AB_Ky%C5%8Ddai_japanese_manga_vol_1.jpg) from [Space Brothers (manga)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Brothers_(manga))

---

Found it! Phys.org's [Japan rocket with manga art launches satellite into space](https://phys.org/news/2016-11-japan-rocket-manga-art-satellite.html):

> **Japan's H-2A rocket, carrying a Himawari-9 weather satellite**, (was) launched on Tanegashima Island on November 2, 2016
>
> Japan's domestically developed mainstay rocket carried two pieces of manga artwork originally drawn by Chuya Koyama, known for his comic book on two brothers who dream about becoming astronauts.
>
> **"We believe it's the first time in the world to launch a rocket with manga art on it,"** said Hirokazu Kosada of Young Astronauts Club Japan, the foundation that organised the rocket art project.
>
> The artworks were created by using 30,000 digital images of photographs and paintings sent by children across Japan, according to Kosada.

[image: screen shot] [image: screen shot]

[image: screen shot] [image: screen shot]

[image: screen shot] [image: screen shot]

**above:** screen shots from the JAXA video "静止気象衛星「ひまわり9号」/H-IIAロケット31号機 打ち上げライブ中継 ｜The live broadcast of the Himawari-9/H-IIA F31 launch"

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of the amateur rocket created by the [Social Media Satellite Development Project(SOMESAT)](http://j.nicotech.jp/somesat) group, whose stated goal is to launch the popular Vocaloid character Hatsune Miku into space.

On September 2009 in Nevada, SOMESAT participated in the eXtreme Performance Rocket Ships(XPRS) competition with a rocket decorated with an illustration of deformed Miku:

[image: SOMESAT's rocket with Miku decoration]

The rocket flew to a height of 1.5km before returning so unfortunately can't be said to have reached space.

Tangentially to the question SOMESAT was also one of several public organizations who contributed to a message plaque attached to JAXA's Venus Climate Orbiter Akatsuki. The image below shows a test print of the panels in the background.

[image: Test prints of panels on akatsuki]

The panels feature Hatsune Miku and was launched into space with Akatsuki on the 21st May 2010.

*Image Sources:*
https://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/0910/08/news011.html
https://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1002/23/news024.html

Comment: Excellent find! I'm remembering something that presumably was space-worthy; at least crossing the Karman line if not  also capable of putting something (small) in orbit, but I really like this possibility, thanks!

Comment: [found it!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44621/12102)

Comment: Fun fact, Japanese "astronauts" are called animenauts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of the rockets of [Interstellar Technologies](http://www.istellartech.com/english)? You asked [a question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30210/31429) about then a while ago, and their rockets have manga-esque logos.

Comment: I definitely don't remember all my questions, thanks! But the one I'm remembering really had manga cartoon characters painted on the side prominently. I don't see that in the images in my previous question. Still, it could be a different launch by the same company.

Comment: [found it!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44621/12102)